# Не могу найти как инициализировать ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ECMAScript 6 уже можно использовать?
Как там определить его, чтобы браузер понял, что это ECMAScript 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для использования всех возможностей ECMAScript 6(или ECMAScript 2015, как он теперь называется), сейчас лучше использовать транслятор ECMAScript 6 -> ECMAScript 5, например [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io),
так вы получите удобство при написании кода и полную совместимость с браузерами.

Answer (score 3):

Если браузер поддерживает фичи из ECMAScript 6, используйте.

Поддерживает ли ваш браузер ECMAScript 6, можно посмотреть [тут](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).